# Android Layout for different phone and tablets

Tags: android

I want to design screen UI. that should support all the phones and tablets (also support orientations) with of different screen sizes and densities do i have to make different res-folder for all the devices with different orientations ? What is the best way to design my screen  UI. that should support all the phones and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Constraintlayout` we want to use only one layout its the better way other than you have to create different size UI.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

There is no "silver bullet", i suppose) It's problem solving individually. 
If you have not so complicated UI, you can use [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)
If you have extremely complicated UI with differences between screen orientation, or between screen sizes - then better to use resources. More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)